# Is the scroll saw/sabre saw/jigsaw question a dupe of the sabre saw/jigsaw question?

Tags: discussion

Is [Are there any differences between jigsaws, sabre saws, or scroll saws?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/are-there-any-differences-between-jigsaws-sabre-saws-or-scroll-saws) a dupe of [What is the difference between a sabre saw and a jig saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/what-is-the-difference-between-a-sabre-saw-and-a-jig-saw)?

I almost marked the new question a dupe of the older one, but the older one asks for clarification on whether *sabre saw* refers to a jigsaw or recip saw. Incidentally, one of the answers also mentions a scroll saw, but the original question does not mention a scroll saw.

I could see an argument to simply mark the older question as a dupe of the newer question, but that would be confusing because one question mentions scroll saws and the other one mentions reciprocating saws instead.

We could also edit one of the questions to include all 4 saws and merge the answers (I think), but I don't think that's a very good solution either because it would render several answers incomplete, including the current "best answer" on the older question.

Is it reasonable to mark one question as a dupe of the other, perhaps with appropriate edits to make one strictly reference a subset of the tools referenced in the other question, or should we leave them separate?

Answer (score 4):

I'm leaning toward modifying the new question to cover all the bases then mark the old one as a dup of the new one.  It leaves the old answers alone, and we get a question that will be THE main question for future dups.

Comment: Should we edit the question to include reciprocating saws for sake of completeness?